# How to inherit paginate/count methods in RecordView controller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to understand why Method 2 fails and what is best way to to re-use views.

Our app is using FlaskBootstrapSecurity as the base pattern.  We've customize the app.controller to have a 'RecordList' (see Method #1).  All plugins will have lists that need pagination... so I wanted to avoid duplicating the pagination code... thus I tried other methods

Method #2 fails by saying that Plugin1 class does not exist on -- super(Plugin1...).**initi**() .   If I use the '*arg, **kwargs' within the init functions, the registry of the blueprint classes fails because it says I am providing args when there are none?

I am testing Method 3 now.

Can someone explain why the Plugin1 class does not work in method 2 ?

### Common to all Cases

app/controller.py

```
import os
from flask.views import MethodView, MethodViewType
from flask import current_app, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask.ext.paginate import Pagination
from flask._compat import with_metaclass


class ViewMeta(MethodViewType):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(ViewMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        #***DO STUFF **
           # The following fails if *args, **kwargs are used in __init__ of RecordList
           bp.add_url_rule(route, view_func=cls().as_view(endpoint))


class BaseView(with_metaclass(ViewMeta, MethodView)):
    route = NotImplemented
    blueprint = NotImplemented
```

### METHOD #1 -- no **init**,   override the methods

app/controller.py

```
class RecordList(TemplateView):

    # No __init__ 
    def count(self):
        return NotImplemented

    def paginate(self, page, per_page):
        return NotImplemented
```

app/app/plugins/PLUGIN1/controller.py

```
class Plugin1List(RecordList):
    blueprint = plugin
    route = '/Plugin1'
    route_name = 'Plugin1'
    template_name = 'Plugin1.html'
    decorators = [register_menu(plugin, '.Plugin1.Plugin1', 'Plugin1 List'),
                  login_required, 
                  roles_required('PlugIn1')]

    # No __init__
    def count(self):
        return Plugin1_Database.objects.count()

    def paginate(self, page, per_page):
        return Plugin1_Database.objects.paginate(page, per_page)
```

### METHOD #2 -- use **init**

```
class RecordList(TemplateView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        init ADDED to default self.db 
        '''
        super(RecordList,self).__init__()
        #super(RecordList,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.db = None

    def count(self):
        return self.db.objects.count()

    def paginate(self, page, per_page):
        return self.db.objects.paginate(page, per_page)
```

app/app/plugins/PLUGIN1/controller.py

```
class Plugin1List(RecordList):
    # initialize local vars (see Method #1)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Plugin1List,self).__init__()
        self.db = Plugin1_Database

    # count/paginate default to parent class
```

### METHOD #3 -- use local var in class

app/controller.py

```
class RecordList(TemplateView):
    database = NotImplemented

    def count(self):
        return self.database.objects.count()

    def paginate(self, page, per_page):
        return self.database.objects.paginate(page, per_page)
```

app/app/plugins/PLUGIN1/controller.py

```
class RecordList(TemplateView):
    database = Plugin1_Database
    ## NO __init__

    # count/paginate default to parent class
```

Comment: Method 3 works.   I know I read somewhere in Flask doc that it is best to put common handling in app/controller.   But still waiting to see if anyone has done Method #2.  -- Will close if don't hear back.

Comment: Are you on python 2 or 3?